# How can get first 3 orders from all clients?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got 2 tables in a MySQL database.

```
tbl_clients

id | name
1  | Mike
2  | John
3  | Dave
.........
N  | N

tbl_orders

id | order_date  | price | client_id
1  | 2018-03-19  | 1000  | 1
2  | 2018-03-19  | 5000  | 2
3  | 2018-05-19  | 3000  | 3
................
N  | N           |  N    | N
```

In my task for some statistic reasons i need to take first 3 orders, by clients with id = 2 and 3.

Is it possible to get data by one query and how can i get it?

Comment: `ORDER BY order_date LIMIT 3`

Comment: Have you tried something ? Have you googled ? Didn't you find similar question in Stack overflow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0, you can simply use `row_number()`.  One option in earlier versions is a correlated subquery -- assuming `order_date` is unique:

```
select o.*
from tbl_orders o
where o.order_date <= (select o2.order_date
                       from tbl_orders o2
                       where o2.client_id = o.client_id
                       order by o2.order_date asc
                       limit 2, 1
                      );
```

You can add `where o.client_id in (2, 3)` in the outer query if you really want to limit this to just 2 clients.